# PL/SQL loop table columes to variable

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql

I have a table with two columes: product (varchar) and usage (varchar). I need to loop the table to one variable in the format "product;usage;product;usage...". How can this be done? The following loop does not work:

```
FOR product IN (SELECT product FROM licence_check) LOOP
    product_usage :=  (licence_check.product || ';' ||  licence_check.usage);
  END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does it have to be a loop? For not-that-many values, `LISTAGG` might do the job:

```
SQL> select listagg(dname||';'||loc, ';') within group (order by deptno) result
  2  from dept;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACCOUNTING;NEW YORK;RESEARCH;DALLAS;SALES;CHICAGO;OPERATIONS;BOSTON

SQL>
```

If it has to be a LOOP, I'd say that you miss concatenation with the PRODUCT_USAGE itself. Have a look:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_result varchar2(100);
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select dname, loc from dept) loop
  5      l_result := l_result || cur_r.dname ||';'||cur_r.loc ||';';
                     -----------
                     This is what you miss
  6    end loop;
  7    dbms_output.put_line(rtrim(l_result, ';'));
  8  end;
  9  /
ACCOUNTING;NEW YORK;RESEARCH;DALLAS;SALES;CHICAGO;OPERATIONS;BOSTON

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```